# Как изменить содержимое тега?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

```
<p id="1">
```

Пытаюсь регулярными выражениями заменить содержимое тега `p`.

Написал регулярное выражение:

```
text = re.sub(r'<p id="\d{1,}">', '???', i)
```

Не могу понять, как на выходе получить вот такое:

```
<p class="test" id="1">
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать так? `'<p id="1">'.replace('<p', '<p class="test" ')`

Comment: Не используйте регулярные выражения для работы с HTML, есть для этого специальные библиотеки, например BeautifulSoup.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, скорее всего потому что надо выбрать параграфы с числовыми id.

Answer (score 3):

Cогласен с [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1284297/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5#comment2264198_1284297): попробуйте [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<p id="1">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.find('p')['class'] = 'test'
```

в итоге в `soup` будет:

```
>>> soup
<p class="test" id="1"></p>
```

сделайте его строкой, если нужно...

Comment: Где выбор только тех параграфов, у которых id числовой?

Comment: @Qwertiy у автора "заменить содержимое тега p", про числовое id - ни полслова: был p с id, добавился атрибут class... мне уже несколько раз замечали, что не нужно придумывать за автора, сам скажет, если понадобится уточнение... судя по последней дате посещения автора этого вопроса - ему ничего не нужно ;)

Comment: Так в его регулярке это есть: `r'<p id="\d{1,}">'`.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы сохранить id, надо поместить его в захватываемую группу и подставить её значение. Фиксированный текст можно было бы просто скопипастить, но я предпочитаю поместить в захватываемую группу и его, чтобы в случае дальнейших изменений не приходилось синхронизировать два места. https://ideone.com/gS3Y40

```
import re

s = '<p id="1">'
print(re.sub(r'(<p)\s+(id="\d+">)', r'\1 class="test" \2', s))
```

Другой вариант - использовать предпросмотр вперёд: https://ideone.com/LLl4A2

```
import re

s = '<p id="1">'
print(re.sub(r'<p(?=\s+id="\d+">)', r'<p class="test"', s))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126313/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----).